# Pandas: for a query in a column, create me a new column with input = True for these values else False

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                    time       price          macd        signal  
19   2019-02-01 00:07:00  0.00234500  1.806661e-06  1.806661e-06   
25   2019-02-01 00:07:00  0.00234530  2.035251e-06  2.019595e-06   
44   2019-02-01 00:10:15  0.00235140  2.375171e-06  2.362027e-06   
61   2019-02-01 00:13:30  0.00235887  1.904017e-06  1.897910e-06       
 macd_histogram cross  
    19      0.000000e+00        
    25      1.565609e-08        
    44      1.314483e-08        
    61      6.106954e-09
```

This is a result from the following: `df.loc[(df.macd_histogram > percentile_low) & (df.macd_histogram < percentile_high)]`, what I would need is for those rows, create a column 'cross' and set the value to True, else False. I tried with an if statement but it did not work... any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign boolean mask to column:

```
df['cross'] = (df.macd_histogram > percentile_low) & (df.macd_histogram < percentile_high)
```

Or use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False`:

```
df['cross'] = df.macd_histogram.between(percentile_low, percentile_high, inclusive=False)
```